# Как вывести данные из таблицы используя checkbox с пом-ю Angular

Tags: html, css, angularjs

```html
<section>
  <table class="table" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
    <thead>
      <tr class="first-line-table">
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Город</td>
        <td>Название</td>
        <td>Выполнить до</td>
        <td>Сумма</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="x in id | filter:test">{{ x }}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="x in city | filter:test">{{ x }}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="x in text | filter:test">{{ x }}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="x in date | filter:test">{{ x }}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="x in sum | filter:test">{{ x }} &#8381;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
</section>


<li class="point"><input type="checkbox"> Персональное </li>
<li class="point"><input type="checkbox"> Ночное</li>
<li class="point"><input type="checkbox"> Срочное</li>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вопрос. Не очень понятно, что вы подразумеваете под *вывести данные из таблицы*?